# How to send audit logs with audisp-remote and receive them with netcat

Tags: centos, logs, freebsd, netcat, linux-audit

I am trying to configure a CentOS 7 running in VirtualBox to send its audit logs to the host which is FreeBSD 10.3. Ideally, I'd like to receive the logs with FreeBSD's [`auditdistd(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=auditdistd&sektion=8&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) but for now I'd just like to be able to use netcat for that.

**My problem is that netcat doesn't get any data.**

## Details

1. When I run `service auditd status` I get the following results:

> ```
> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  auditd.service
> auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
>    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-08-19 11:35:42 CEST; 3s ago
>   Process: 2216 ExecStartPost=/sbin/augenrules --load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>  Main PID: 2215 (auditd)
>    CGroup: /system.slice/auditd.service
>            ├─2215 /sbin/auditd -n
>            └─2218 /sbin/audispd
>
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote terminated unexpectedly
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote terminated unexpectedly
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote terminated unexpectedly
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote terminated unexpectedly
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote has exceeded max_restarts
> Aug 19 11:35:42 hephaistos audispd[2218]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
> ```

## Setup

### Network Setup

1. CentOS and FreeBSD are connected on a host-only network. I've assigned them the following IP's:

- CentOS: 192.168.56.101
- FreeBSD: 192.168.56.1

### FreeBSD Setup

1. I've got netcat listening on port 60:

   ```
    nc -lk 60
   ```

The connection works. I can use `nc 192.168.56.1 60` on CentOS to send data to FreeBSD.

### CentOS Setup

0. The kernel version is: `4.7.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 24 18:15:29 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.
1. The version of Linux Audit userspace is 2.6.6.
2. auditd is running and actively logging to `/var/log/audit.log`.
3. The auditing rules in `/etc/audit/rules.d/` are well configured.
4. The configuration of `/etc/audisp/audisp-remote.conf` looks like this:

   ```
    remote-server = 192.168.56.1
    port = 60
    local_port = any
    transport = tcp
    mode = immediate
   ```
5. I've got two default files in `/etc/audisp/plugins.d/`: `syslog.conf` and `af_unix.conf` and both of them are not active. I've added `af-remote.conf` and it looks like this:

   ```
    # This file controls the audispd data path to the
    # remote event logger. This plugin will send events to
    # a remote machine (Central Logger).

    active = yes
    direction = out
    path = /sbin/audisp-remote
    type = always
    #args =
    format = string
   ```

It is a modified example from [the official repository (link)](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/audisp/plugins/remote/au-remote.conf).

5. Here's the content of `/etc/audisp/audispd.conf`:

   ```
    q_depth = 150
    overflow_action = SYSLOG
    priority_boost = 4
    max_restarts = 10
    name_format = HOSTNAME
   ```

---

<sup>I'll be happy to provide more details if needed.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if everything here is needed to succeed. Nevertheless, this is a configuration which works so that I am able to receive Linux Audit logs with a netcat on FreeBSD.

1. CentOS:`/etc/audisp/audisp-remote.conf`:

   ```
   remote_server = 192.168.56.1
   port = 60
   local_port = 60
   transport = tcp
   mode = immediate
   queue_depth = 200
   format = managed
   ```
2. CentOS:`/etc/audisp/plugins.d/au-remote.conf`:

   ```
   active = yes
   direction = out
   path = /sbin/audisp-remote
   type = always
   args = /etc/audisp/audisp-remote.conf
   format = string
   ```
3. CentOS:`/etc/audit/auditd.conf`:

   ```
   local_events = yes
   log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
   # Send logs to the server.  Don't save them.
   write_logs = no
   log_format = RAW
   log_group = root
   priority_boost = 8
   num_logs = 5
   disp_qos = lossy
   dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
   name_format = hostname
   max_log_file = 6
   max_log_file_action = ROTATE
   action_mail_acct = root
   space_left = 75
   space_left_action = SYSLOG
   admin_space_left = 50
   admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
   disk_full_action = SUSPEND
   disk_error_action = SUSPEND

   ##tcp_listen_port =
   tcp_listen_queue = 5
   tcp_max_per_addr = 1
   use_libwrap = yes
   ##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
   tcp_client_max_idle = 0

   enable_krb5 = no
   krb5_principal = auditd
   ##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
   distribute_network = no
   ```
4. FreeBSD:`/etc/hosts.allow`:

   ```
    ALL : ALL : allow
   ```

   I don't know if this one is needed though + it might be a bad idea.

---

That's it. Now you just have to run `nc -lk 60` on FreeBSD and `service auditd restart` on CentOS. In my case however netcat seems to be receiving/printing every record at least two times which seems rather unusual.

Comment: One note i wanted to share is that /sbin/audisp-remote isn't in the audit rpm (e.g. audit-2.8.5-4.el7.x86_64); it's in audispd-plugins (e.g. audispd-plugins-2.8.5-4.el7.x86_64). I had to go find that and install it as it wasn't already installed on my RHEL 7 (or CENTOS7) systems.