# Can kernel know when a file being read?

Tags: files, process, monitoring

I would like to know when a specific file is being read and logs the process ID and executable name and also notify me by sending an email using mail.

Can kernel module do this? Is kernel module the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html).

Comment: inotify can tell you when a file is opened for reading, would that be good enough?

Comment: @JuliePelletier inotify can tell when a file is accessed, but not which process did it.

Comment: You can use this command # lsof  to check it.Maybe this # lsof command can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a file invokes kernel code, so the kernel always knows. The question is how to get it to notify you.

On Linux, you can use the [audit subsystem](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Defining_Audit_Rules_and_Controls.html). Run [`auditctl`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) to add a rule to watch this file:

```
auditctl -w /path/to/specific/file
```

The event is sent to the audit logs. You can request audit events to be emailed by configuring [audispd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/audispd.8.html) — see [How to send audit logs with audisp-remote and receive them with netcat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304260/how-to-send-audit-logs-with-audisp-remote-and-receive-them-with-netcat) for examples. Alternatively, set up email of audit reports; see [Scott Pack's “Stump the Chump with Auditd 01”](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/stump-the-chump-with-auditd-01/).

Comment: This utitlity is great. However, if I use $cat <file>, this does not get logged by the tool. Why is that and how can I keep track of $cat <file> to read files?

Comment: @dannycrane Access by `cat` gets logged, like from any other program. If you don't see an entry in the audit logs (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`) then you aren't running the audit daemon or you didn't set the rule with the right path.

Comment: but vim <file> gets logged....

Comment: @dannycrane Strange. Does adding `-p rwxa` to the `auditctl` call make any difference? (I think it's the default so it shouldn't make a difference but I don't see what could be the difference between vim and cat.)